# silverstripe dopublish function for ModelAdmin managed Pages

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe, modeladmin

in the silverstripe backend I´m managing certain PageTypes via a ModelAdmin. That works fine so far, the only thing i can´t figure out is how to make a Page being "Published" when saving it.

Thats my code:

```
class ProjectPage extends Page { 
    public function onAfterWrite() {
        $this->doPublish();
        parent::onAfterWrite();
    }
}
```

At the moment I can still see the ModelAdmin-created Pages in the Sitetree and I can see they are in Draft Mode. If I use the code above I get this error:
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
.../framework/model/DataList.php

Many thx,
Florian

Comment: There are now some modules around for managing page types in a ModelAdmin, e.g. https://github.com/Little-Giant/silverstripe-catalogmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why you get "Maximum execution time exceeded" is because `$this->doPublish();` calls `$this->write();` which then calls `$this->onAfterWrite();`. And there you have your endless loop.
So doing this in `onAfterWrite()` or `write()` doesn't really work

you should just display the save & publish button instead of the save button
But I guess its easier said than done.
Well adding a button is actually just a few lines, but we also need a provide the functions that do what the button says it does.

This sounds like the perfect call for creating a new Module that allows proper handling of Pages in model admin. I have done this in SS2.4, and I have a pretty good idea of how to do it in SS3, but no time this week, poke me on the silverstripe irc channel on the weekend, maybe I have time on the weekend.

Comment: having a module for this would be great! i've been using the 'remodeladmin' approach from unclecheese in 2.4; guess things should work out for 3.0 as well. had a quick look and think this one here might help adding the 'publish/unpublish' actions: https://github.com/silverstripe/sapphire/pull/526

Comment: hello! thx! another thing that would help me, would be to get also unpublished pages when doing this in a controller: $projectPages = ProjectPage::get();

Comment: It's not a module, but see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13410320/1017611) for a ready made extension that should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same need/lack and I built a workaround that seems to work for me, maybe it can be useful.

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
if(!$this->isPublished() || $this->getIsModifiedOnStage())
{
    $this->publish('Stage', 'Live');
    Controller::curr()->redirectBack(); 
}
parent::onAfterWrite();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that extends `ModelAdmin` and define an `updateEditForm` function to add a publish button to the actions in the `GridFieldDetailForm` component of the `GridField`.

```php
public function updateEditForm($form) {

    if ( ! singleton($this->owner->modelClass)->hasExtension('Versioned') ) return;

    $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($this->owner->modelClass);
    $gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldDetailForm')->setItemEditFormCallback(function ($form) {
        $form->Actions()->push(FormAction::create('doPublish', 'Save & Publish'));
    });
}
```

Then create a class that extends `GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest` to provide an action handler for your publish button.

```php
public function doPublish($data, $form) {
    $return = $this->owner->doSave($data, $form);
    $this->owner->record->publish('Stage', 'Live');
    return $return;
}
```

Make sure the extensions are applied and you're done.

Or, you could just [grab all the code you need from GitHub](https://github.com/drzax/silverstripe-bits/tree/master/VersionedModelAdmin).