# Silverstripe adding pages via model admin doesn't update CMS

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I need to create a model admin class to be able to create pages in model admin style.  It used to work on 2.4 but not since LeftAndMain::ForceReload has been deprecated in 3.1 it doesn't work anymore.  Here is a fragment of my CustomCalendarEvent class:

```
public function onBeforeWrite(){
parent::onBeforeWrite();
$parent_calendar_page = Calendar::get()->first();
$this->ParentID = $parent_calendar_page->ID;
}

public function onAfterWrite(){
parent::onAfterWrite();
if(!$this->isPublished()){
$this->publish('Stage', 'Live');
$this->flushCache();
// This doesn't work anymore on SS 3.1
// LeftAndMain::ForceReload();
} 
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the answers to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157964/silverstripe-dopublish-function-for-modeladmin-managed-pages?

Comment: I have read that question but the above code is different in the sense that I only allow it to publish once.  That is the purpose of checking if the DO/Page has been published or not (If(!$this->isPublished()). I didn't have any problem publishing the page, the problem is more on the ajax call when you go to the Page section of the CMS and check on the newly created Page from model admin. Not sure if my explanation made any sense. To give you an idea of what I am trying to point out I left LeftAndMain::ForceReload() commented to illustrate my goal.

Comment: Ok. I used the recommended solution by drzax unfortunately the same thing happens, the page gets saved via save/publish button but doesn't update Tree management section of the CMS with the new page published. You still need to refresh the browser to see the page added to the tree.